# GCP Compute Engine // Connection refused ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Working on GCE.. I think boot disk exceed capacity. Suddenly freeze.
and following error occurred when

`gcloud compute ssh`

```
ssh: connect to host {my external address} port 22: Connection refused 
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

**Status**

`gcloud compute firewall-rules list`

```
NAME                                     NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                                                       DENY  DISABLED
allow-superset-related                   default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:22,tcp:8080,tcp:80,tcp:443,tcp:8088,tcp:8888,tcp:13080        False
default-allow-8080                       default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:8080,tcp:15672,tcp:5555                                       False
default-allow-http                       default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80                                                            False
default-allow-https                      default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443                                                           False
default-allow-icmp                       default  INGRESS    65534     icmp                                                              False
default-allow-internal                   default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp                                      False
default-allow-rdp                        default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389                                                          False
default-allow-ssh                        default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22                                                            False
```

`nmap {my external ip}`

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-10 19:14 KST
Nmap scan report for **
Host is up (0.0032s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
2869/tcp filtered icslap
4444/tcp filtered krb524

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.25 seconds
```

`gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port {my_instance}`

```
...

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Raise network interfaces.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network is Online.
You are in emerg
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue
```

serial port is not interactive.

can anyone help?

Comment: This article shows how to resize the root file system for Debian based systems. Almost identical steps for other Linux distributions: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize your disk following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) or with the following command:

```
gcloud compute disks resize DISK_NAME --size DISK_SIZE
```

Or with the Console:

1. Go to the [Disks](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/disks?_ga=2.15790646.1673104947.1599483183-638966553.1591892739) page to see a list of zonal persistent disks in your project.
2. Click the name of the disk that you want to resize.
3. On the disk details page, click **Edit**.
4. In the **Size** field, enter the new size for your disk.
5. Click Save to apply your changes to the disk.

After you resize the disk, you must [resize the file system](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions) so that the operating system can access the additional space.

Note: Do not resize boot disks beyond 2 TB because this is the limit.

Comment: next section in above link solve my problem. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you was able to solve your problem.