# Google Cloud SSH: /usr/bin/bash exited with return code [255]

Tags: ssh, cloud, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Currently, I am running a data retriever on the cloud and save the data in the database on a docker container. Until today, I was able to ssh into the instance (and therefore the docker container), but now I am not able to do so anymore. When I do the ssh, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Doing the suggested troubleshoot, it seems that there is no problem with any of the issues tested.

I have looked at other stackoverflow questions, such as [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827730/gcp-compute-engine-connection-refused-error-gcloud-compute-ssh-usr-bin-s). My assumption is that indeed the disk is full, so I tried to increase the disk size. However, since I am not able to ssh into the instance (also not after increasing the persistent disk size, using `gcloud compute disks resize`), I am unable to format the disk as suggested in [format disk on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#gcloud). Further, I tried removing the ssh keys and adding them again, but to no avail. Right now, I'm a bit lost.

Do you know a solution to ssh into the VM instance again?

Looking forwards to your replies.

Comment: Does the VM have an ephemeral IP address and has that address changed? Connect to the VM serial console and review debug output for errors.